# Comments on protected worksheet columns

Tags: c#, xlsx, epplus, worksheet, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to export data to Excel. The export is working fine, I'd like to have my first two columns protected so the user can only edit the third. That's working great.

However, I add comments to cells and the comments in the cells that are protected don't show.

My Google-Fu eluded me and I could not find anything on this topic. I'm not exactly an Excel expert though and on top of that I only have OpenOffice to test. So I don't really know if what I want is even possible. Maybe this is normal Excel behavior or normal OpenOffice behavior?

```
for (int index = 0; index < lines.Length; index++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[index + 2, 1].Value = lines[index].Name;
    worksheet.Cells[index + 2, 2].Value = lines[index].DataSource;
    worksheet.Cells[index + 2, 3].Value = lines[index].DataDestination;

    worksheet.Comments.Add(worksheet.Cells[index + 2, 1], "my comment", "XXX");
}

using (var autoFitRange = worksheet.Cells["A1:C" + (lines.Length + 1)])
{
    autoFitRange.AutoFitColumns();
}

worksheet.Protection.AllowInsertRows = false;
worksheet.Protection.AllowSort = true;
worksheet.Protection.AllowSelectUnlockedCells = true;
worksheet.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = true;
worksheet.Protection.AllowFormatCells = true;
worksheet.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = true;

worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;

// if I unlock the column, the comment will be available
//     worksheet.Column(1).Style.Locked = false;

worksheet.Column(3).Style.Locked = false;
```

So how do I make the comment be available on locked columns? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Creating file and opening in excel (not open office) shows comment on locked cell correctly, so I guess it's open office issue.

Comment: @Evk Thanks for the hint, I'll try to get my hands on an Excel version then... I think there were free readers the last time I checked.

Comment: There are quite a lot of differences in display between open office and excel, so if end users are expected to use excel - you really need to have it too.